# Pl/SQL - oracle 9i - Manual Pivoting

Tags: plsql, oracle9i

We have a table which has three columns in it:

```
Customer_name, Age_range, Number_of_people.
1              1-5         10
1              5-10        15
```

We need to return all the number of people in different age ranges as rows of a single query. If we search for customer #1, the query should just return one row:

```
Header- Age Range (1-5)             Age Range (5-10)
        10                             15
```

We needed to get all the results in a single row; When I query for customer 1, the result should be only number of people in a single row group by `age_range`.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Notice how every answer contains a query with a different output?  That's because this question is really vague. The comments you made in response to @Ryan Bates' answer should be incorporated into the question and you should try to clarify what exactly it is you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually perform a pivot:

```
  SELECT   SUM(CASE WHEN age_range = '5-10' 
                    THEN number_of_people 
                    ELSE NULL END) AS nop5,
           SUM(CASE WHEN age_range = '10-15' 
                    THEN number_of_people 
                    ELSE NULL END) AS nop10
    FROM   customers
   WHERE   customer_name = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are easy solutions with 10g and 11g using LISTGAGG, COLLECT, or other capabilities added after 9i but I believe that the following will work in 9i.
Source (http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/one-row.html)

You will just need to replace deptno with customer_name and ename with Number_of_people

```
SELECT deptno, 
       LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ename,','))
FROM   ( SELECT deptno,
                ename,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename) -1 AS seq 
         FROM   emp ) 
WHERE  connect_by_isleaf = 1
CONNECT BY seq = PRIOR seq +1 AND deptno = PRIOR deptno 
START WITH seq = 1;


    DEPTNO CONCATENATED
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

3 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create a stored `FUNCTION` which means you can access it at any time.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION number_of_people(p_customer_name VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_number_of_people NUMBER;
  v_result VARCHAR2(500);

  CURSOR c1
  IS
    SELECT Number_of_people FROM the_table WHERE Customer_name = p_customer_name;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO v_number_of_people;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

    v_result := v_result || v_number_of_people || ' ' || CHR(13);
  END;
END;
```

To run it, use:

`SELECT number_of_people(1) INTO dual;`

Hope this helps, and please let me know if there are any errors, I didn't testrun the function myself.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
select Number_of_people
from table
where Customer_name = 1
```

Are we missing some detail?

Comment: ahh i think i didnt explain it properly. I needed to get all the results in a single row, like when i query for customer 1, the result should be all number of people in a single row group by age_range

Comment: OK, then you could do `SELECT Age_Range, Number_of_people from table group_by Age_Range`. That would return multiple rows though. Do you need that simplified to a single row?

Comment: Yes, i just need one row returned with ONLY all the values of number of people in its column.

Comment: That's a little more involved. I'd suggest looking at this article for a few ideas: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_display_multiple_column_values_same_rows.htm

Comment: @sandy: Please edit the question to clarify what you actually want. Perhaps give some more examples.